# Android - Facebook Share Button not clickable

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I am trying to implement the "Share" function provided by FaceBook to post a simple message from the current screen of my Android app. I am able to trigger the show ShareDialog when the activity is launch however I cannot replicate this when the ShareButton is click, instead content behind the button is clicked.

In the Facebook documentation there is no use of a OnClickListener instead:

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
    .build();
shareDialog.show(content);
```

Followed by the button

```
ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_share_button);
shareButton.setShareContent(content);
```

From my understanding this is meant to have a built in listener to trigger the `setShareContent` when the `shareButton` is click

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends MainActivitySettings {

CallbackManager callbackManager;
ShareDialog shareDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                 .setContentTitle("Title Description")
                 .setContentDescription("Some Content Description")
                 .build();



        ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_share);
        shareButton.setShareContent(content);
        shareDialog.show(content);
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried this on the sample projects bundled with the SDK? e.g. [this sample](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/001984c85bbb5ccb7a3df4e33fe3090d22a8ac88/samples/Iconicus/src/com/example/iconicus/MainActivity.java#L75-L81)?